# Chef and ruby: how to convert a array into a set

Tags: ruby

I have an array that looks like this:

```
nodes = ['server1','server1','server2']
```

In a chef recipe I need to convert into a set before I pass to a template erb.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This pattern works with Set, Matrix, JSON etc.; it is the first thing to try.

```
require 'set'
nodes = ['server1','server1','server2']
p nodes.to_set # #<Set: {"server1", "server2"}>
```

Comment: The `p` is a method for coders - what do I have here?; it is short-hand for `puts nodes.to_set.inspect`. It is used here only for demonstrating the results of the `to_set` method.

Answer (score 14):

if you want to make it unique (as a set is unique) but still as an array, you can use |[]

```
nodes = ['server1','server1','server2']
nodes|[] 
# or nodes |= [] # for inplace operation

# => ["server1", "server2" ]
```

Comment: That is interesting.